# How to configure Quasar plugins without Quasar CLI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loading, quasar-framework

I added Quasar to my pre-existing Vue CLI project with `vue add quasar`.

Now I'm trying to use the [Loading plugin](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/loading), but I can't get it to work.

Here's what I have related to Quasar/Vue setup:

```js
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'

Vue.use(Quasar, {
  config: {},
  components: { /* not needed if importStrategy is not 'manual' */ },
  directives: { /* not needed if importStrategy is not 'manual' */ },
  plugins: {},
  cssAddon: true,
  extras: [
    'ionicons-v4',
    'material-icons',
    'material-icons-outlined',
    'material-icons-round',
    'material-icons-sharp',
    'mdi-v3',
    'eva-icons',
    'fontawesome-v5',
    'themify'
  ]
})
```

I tried with the options below to no avail. Any ideas?

```js
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'

Vue.use(Quasar, {
  ...,
  framework: {
    plugins: [
      'Loading'
    ]
  },
  ...
})
```

and

```js
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'

Vue.use(Quasar, {
  ...
  plugins: ['Loading'],
  ...
})
```

Comment: This seems to be the right config. How do you try to use it?

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut `this.$q.loading.hide()` which tells me $q doesn't exists

Comment: If you are adding Quasar to existing project, then this.$q will not work, you need to use global Quasar object instead - read about this here - https://quasar.dev/start/umd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I didn't use quasar-cli to add Quasar to my application I had to resort to global calls to the plugin. Here's how I ended up doing and it is the same thing that @Alex Brohshtut suggested in his comment.

`main.ts`

```js
import { Loading } from 'quasar';

http.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  Loading.show({
    delay: 500,
    message: 'Please wait...'
  });
  return config
})

http.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  Loading.hide();
  return response
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this to work in a similar vue-cli setup with Vue 3 and Quasar 2 with some help from [the "Using Vue" docs in quasar.](https://next.quasar.dev/start/how-to-use-vue)

`quasar-user-options.js`

```
import './styles/quasar.sass'
import { Notify } from 'quasar'

// To be used on app.use(Quasar, { ... })
export default {
  config: {
  },
  plugins: [Notify]
}
```

And in `main.js` it's used like:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'
import quasarUserOptions from './quasar-user-options'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).use(Quasar, quasarUserOptions).mount('#app')
```

I think in your setup you just weren't importing the plugin when you added it to the plugins config.